# Best way to frequently save data into Mysql database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Currently I am using a PHP script which is called every second from a JavaScript to save data from different crypto currencies into my Mysql database.

The data which I save into the database is coming from Exchanges like Poloniex, you only need to call the API link from the Exchange and you get back the data in JSON format. And I need to update the data really every second because I download from there crypto currency charts for nearly 100 pairs, so they need to be actual all the time.

But I am currently not sure if what I am doing is a good way and if with other ways you could make this better.

I must say, I don't have really much experience with other coding languages then PHP and JavaScript, so with this 2 languages I was able to create what I need, but with some time the data which I need to save will become bigger and bigger and I am not sure if with PHP and JavaScript this will work good enough.

I would be happy if you can give me your tips what you think about my solution and do you know other better solutions?

Comment: i can say that using php, javascript  , and mysql it's not a bad choise . it's depend also about your server resources .

Comment: if your php's configuration is ok, and your mysql is ok too, it must be ok. Even if it s better to use directly php's server to fetch data from your API. the 1st problem could be mysql, which can be changed by a nosql database. But if you have a historic, nice indexes, it must be enough

Comment: thank you for your comments, actually i have no other codeing language then php and javascript but i did hear from some people using somethink like C++ or Java for codeing that could be better

Comment: Usually PHP scrips open and closes a connection each time they are executed. You may try something with a [persistent connection](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/features.persistent-connections.php), eg. a restful webservice.

Comment: You can't replace PHP with C++.  If you are new to coding, don't try Java server too. It is more complicated than php. You can start looking at websockets for faster communication between api, database, and frontend. You don't need to call php script from javascript, you can do it pure php.